# Django form validation not redirecting to the correct url

Tags: python, django, validation

I'm using Django 1.9.8 and having some trouble validating a form for registering users. If there are validation errors, the redirect back to the form is to the incorrect url. The registration url is `localhost:8000/register`. When errors are found (I think that's what's happening, anyway), the page is redirected to `localhost:8000/register/register`. What am I doing incorrectly that is causing the redirect to add an additional `register` argument to the url?

```
#authorization/views.py
class RegisterViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    #GET requests
    def register(self,request):
        return render(request, 'authorization/register.html', {'form': RegisterForm})

    #POST requests
    def create(self,request):
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = User.objects.create_user(username,email,password)
            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/users') #show list of users after saving
        else:
            #return to the form for the user to fix errors & continue registering
            return render(request, 'authorization/register.html', {'form': RegisterForm})
```

Here's the RegisterForm content

```
#authorization/forms.py
class RegisterForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", max_length=30,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'username'}))
    email = forms.CharField(label="Email", max_length=30,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'email'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", max_length=30,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'password', 'type' : 'password'}))
    repassword = forms.CharField(label="RePassword", max_length=30,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'repassword', 'type' : 'password'}))

    def clean_password(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('repassword')
        if password1 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but here's my urls.py

```
#authorization/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^register/', views.RegisterViewSet.as_view({'get' : 'register', 'post' : 'create'})),
]
```

I tested the create method prior to adding the form validation part and it was successfully saving users, so I know it at least was working up to that point.

**Edit - added form contents**

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-error">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}


<form method="post" action="register" id = "RegisterForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p class="bs-component">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ form.email.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.email }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>{{ form.repassword.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.repassword }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </p>
    <p class="bs-component">
        <center>
            <input class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit" value="Register" />
        </center>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show the `register.html` template?

Comment: @knbk added the form

Answer (score 0):

The `action` on your form points to a relative path, `register`. If an url path does not begin with a slash, it will append it after the last slash of the current url. Since the form is being posted to `/register/register`, and your url pattern matches that, that's the url you'll see when an error occurs.

To fix this, you should make it an absolute url (starting with a slash) or make it empty (i.e. `action=''`) to post to the current url.

The most robust way to point the action to the `RegisterViewSet` is to use the `{% url %}` template tag. To use this, you need to give the url a name. It is probably a good idea to add a `$` to the pattern as well, so it only matches if `/register/` is the complete url, and not if it's just the start of the url:

```
# authorization/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.RegisterViewSet.as_view({'get' : 'register', 'post' : 'create'}), name='register'),
]

# authorization/register.html
<form method="post" action="{% url 'register' %}" id="RegisterForm">
...
```

Comment: Changing the form action from what I currently have to what you have shown results in the following error `NoReverseMatch at /register/ Reverse for 'register' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`. However, when I change the action to `' '` like you suggested above, it redirects correctly, but the errors aren't showing. I have code to show errors, which I forgot to copy. I'll update my original post to reflect it.